# Why the following regex [^0-9!a-zA-z#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-/=\\?\\^_`\\{\\|\\}~@\\.]+ for String.split is not working?

Tags: java, regex

I have this regular expression:

```
[^0-9!a-zA-z#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-/=\\?\\^_`\\{\\|\\}~@\\.]+
```

and I am trying to split the email address using

```
[Email]info@emerycommunications.com
```

But the following code in java:

```
String fileStr = "[Email]info@emerycommunications.com";

String invalidCharacters = "[^0-9!a-zA-z#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-/=\\?\\^_`\\{\\|\\}~@\\.]+";

String[] tokens = fileStr.split(invalidCharacters);

for (String token:tokens) {
    if (token.contains("@")) {
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

is giving this output:

```
[Email]info@emerycommunications.com
```

I am completely clueless as `invalidCharacters` variable covers `[` and `]` also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have `A-z` in your character class, and the square bracket characters come between upper case Z and lower case a in ASCII (and Unicode) order. Thus `]` is being considered a valid rather than invalid character - presumably you meant `A-Z` instead.

Comment: Seems to be working now after I replaced A-z with A-Z. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Md.ReazulKarim glad it helped, and welcome to StackOverflow.  Please consider marking the answer as _accepted_ using the tick mark to the left.

Answer (score 4):

This regular expression:

```
[^0-9!a-zA-z#\$%&'\*\+\-/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~@\.]+
```

Matches at least one but as many as there are of any character except the ones *between* the square brackets.  The square brackets themselves are not part of the set of characters.  And most of those backslashes are unnecessary; none of the backslashed characters besides the hyphen is special within a character class.

However, since you have the range `A-z`, which is *uppercase* `A` through *lowercase* `z`, not only do you have the lowercase letters in there twice, but you also have all the characters that come between `Z` and `a`, namely `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, and `` ` ``.  So that's how the brackets are getting into the negated character class.

If that's not what you intend, this regex may be what you're looking for:

```
[^0-9!a-zA-Z#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~@.-]+
```

(Moving the hyphen to the end means it doesn't need to be backslashed)

Comment: The backslashes do not add a literal backslash to the character class.

Comment: @m.buettner I assume this regex is already string-unescaped, so they do get to the regex engine (and escape the punctuation).

Comment: Look at the code; the backslashes are doubled in the actual string, so they do get to the regex engine.

Comment: Also, making a set of unmatched (rather than matched) characters was the askers's intention.

Comment: No, my regex is as seen after String processing. `String invalidCharacters = "[^0-9!a-zA-z#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-/=\\?\\^_`\\{\\|\\}~@\\.]+";`n - all the backslashes are doubled, so they are making it through to the regex engine, where - since they're inside a character class - they include backslash in the character class (or exclude it, since it's negated).

Comment: downvoting for "all they do is add backslash to the set of excluded characters, over and over again". This is incorrect.

Comment: Backslashes within a character class do not mean literal backslashes.

Comment: @m.buettner the backslashes do get to the regex engine. Only one per other punctuation, though.

Comment: @m.buettner you can always avoid escaping within a character class by making a hyphen first and a caret not first.

Comment: However, if _two_ backslashes _did_ get to the regex engine, they _would_ form a literal backslash.

Comment: Thanks, @JanDvorak and m.buettner.  Corrected.

Comment: Trailing hyphen is totally valid, @JanDvorak.  That one I'm sure about. :)